# Bash: reading files and moving into sub-directory

Tags: macos, bash

I have around 1000 files (png) and need to move them into the corresponding directory and their sub-directory.

I do have 26 directories (A - Z) and below each directory the complete alphabet A-Z again. File names are 6 characters/digits long and have a png extension, e.g. e.g. AH2BC0.png

I would need to move the file AH2BC0.png into the directory A and within that directory into the sub-directory H, e.g.A->H->AH2BC0.png.

I have created following script which is not really working as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls >LISTE.txt
for i in LISTE.txt; do
a=$(cat $i | cut -b 1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
b=$(cat $i | cut -b 2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
mkdir -p $a/$b
cat $i | xargs mv $a/$b
rm $i
done
```

Problem is that a) the sub-directory is not created and b) the files are not moved. Any suggestions or better ideas for the script?

Thanks

PS: I guess it's obvious that it's quite some years ago that I have created any bash scripts or coded so please bear with me.
PSS: working on MAC OSX bash 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a post showing a better program to do what you want but I thought I'd show you how to fix yours. Hopefully you'll find it informative.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls >LISTE.txt
for i in LISTE.txt; do
```

This loops over the single value LISTE.txt; replace it with:

```
for i in $(cat LISTE.txt); do
```

to loop over the *contents* of the file instead.

```
    a=$(cat $i | cut -b 1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    b=$(cat $i | cut -b 2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

You want to use `echo` rather than `cat` in the above two lines, as you're after the *name* of the file not its content.

```
    mkdir -p $a/$b
    cat $i | xargs mv $a/$b
```

I don't think the above line does what you think it does... It will attempt to rename the $a/$b directory to C, where C is the *content* of file $i. Replace it with:

```
    mv $i $a/$b
```

The following line is not needed:

```
    rm $i
```

So simply delete it. It would only be necessary if you *copied* rather than moved the files using `mv`.

```
done
```

Here's your complete program after the changes I've suggested.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls >LISTE.txt
for i in $(cat LISTE.txt); do
    a=$(echo $i | cut -b 1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    b=$(echo $i | cut -b 2 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    mkdir -p $a/$b
    mv $i $a/$b
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It definitely was informativ and I'm shocked how many mistakes I made.

Comment: would like to upvote but not able to. I do get the message that I would need 15 reputation to be able to. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
for item in *; do
    first=${item:0:1}
    second=${item:1:1}

    folder="$first/$second"
    mkdir -p $folder
    mv $item $folder/
done
```

Comment: also works just with one error. the second directory name does start two digits and not one. nevertheless, also big thanks.

Comment: Fixed `second=${item:1:2}` should have been `second=${item:1:1}`